# "Insecure origins treated as secure" does not work in Opera

Tags: opera, ssl-certificate, exclude

STR:

1. Go to configuration in Opera: opera://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure
2. Set URL: https://self-signed.badssl.com/
3. Reload Opera
4. Open entered URL from #2.

Results:

- **Expected:** the browser will allow to get into this website.
- **Actual:** it returns error "NET::ERR_CERT_INVALID".

As described in other questions (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40696280/unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure-flag-is-not-working-on-chrome)) it's kind of simple thing to enable.
But in fact it does not work anymore.

Any ideas why?

**UPD 2023-01**

[This post](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/security-dev/c/LlwAeKmvHr4/m/wgjPmj05BAAJ) says `--user-data-dir` also must be supplied. Any official sources about this requirement?
It does not work for me, as URLs in this configuration are remote, not local.

And this browser notice must be a reason why it does not work:
[image: You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure]

Comment: [Change https to http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41441164/unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure-not-recognized-google-chrome)

Comment: @Ramhound, no, that's not an option. I won't have insecure connection via HTTP.

Comment: By enabling the flag, that’s exactly, what you have allowed. Can’t you at least, try it, and verify it works? Given someone else had the exact same problem years ago and indicated that was not indeed the solution?

Comment: Sorry, understood this in opposite. But in the end, it must be the same. Actually, I'm getting following from browser on start: `You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure `. So, it's the same flag. The configuration does not say why might not work. But some forums say user data path must be set. I added link to this post.

Comment: A lot of these types of flags, particularly this specific flag, are incredibly insecure and over the years many of them have been disabled.